# How to post to Facebook Page from a Python app in 2021

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I've created a Python app that pulls data from gov data sources, creates simple graphs and saves them and I want the app to be able to post to a Facebook page I've made. However all the tutorials I can find on this don't have the current Facebook GraphAPI workflow on doing this and it appears to have changed drastically since they were written. Can anyone point me to a tutorial with the 2021 Facebook app access workflow? All I want is to be able to post to the page, I don't want to collect data on who visits the page or collect data at all, just have the app post the information to the page. I've seen some hints that this may be doable with OAuth but to be honest I've gone through so many tutorials that no longer work I've become lost in information overload, most of which no longer seems to apply. This seems like it should be simple, it probably is, but I just don't seem to be able to find a tutorial on doing it. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be gratefully received.

Comment: I also might be confusing what Facebook considers an 'app' and programmatic access, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

### [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

The Graph API Explorer tool allows you to construct and perform Graph API queries and see their responses for any apps on which you have an admin, developer, or tester role.

Prerequisites:

1. A Facebook Developer Account.
2. An app for which you have a role, such as an admin, developer, or tester ([documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app))
3. Facebook page and Page access token

To implement any of Facebook's products and SDKs or access any of their APIs an app is needed. App-types determine which products and APIs are available to your app.

[Step 0:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/explorer#get-token-dropdown)
Get an access-token using Graph API Explorer (short-lived)
[Step 1:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#get-a-page-access-token)
Exchange your short-lived token for a Long-lived (60 days) token Using your app-id, app-secret and access-token

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
  client_id={app-id}&
  client_secret={app-secret}&
  fb_exchange_token={short-lived-user-access-token}"
```

[Step 3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#get-a-page-access-token):
Grant the required permissions to the user access token to perform the task of creating a Post on the Facebook page. Since you own both the app and the page with administrator roles this step is already taken care. To get the page access token

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}?
  fields=access_token&
  access_token={user-access-token}"
```

Step 4:
Curl Command to Post to the facebook page:

```
curl -i -X "POST https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/photos
    ?url={path-to-photo}
    &caption={caption}
    &access_token={page-access-token}"
```

I created a Facebook page to Cross post memes from Reddit. The blog can be found [here](https://medium.com/@rietesh/automating-a-meme-page-5d5a20ad102).

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, off your read your blog now!

Comment: I still can't get the Facebook GraphAPI setup workflow right. The bit you do on Facebook that allows you to make calls to the api in the first place by creating a token. That's the bit I'm struggling with, apologies if my post didn't make that clear. Facebook seems to want me to submit my app for review in order to get the permissions and when I do it gets rejected. I'm fairly certain that I've got that bit all wrong.

Comment: To successfully make calls to the API, you should have done the 1st and 2nd prerequisites. Then you follow this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/explorer#get-token-dropdown

Comment: When connecting to a page I own with my user token, I get this error trying to get the page token (step 3): `(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature.`